# How can I integrate fontawesome with nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, nuxt.js

I have been trying to use fontawesome icons inside nuxt.js, but whenever I run `npm run dev` I get this error `ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/index.es.js Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`

I think that the problem is there is not a free-solid-svg-icons directory, but when I tried to install it with npm, it didn't appear.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you installed this way? 
`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Answer (score 2):

Late but might help, create plugins folder if not created in root folder, add fontawesome.js file and import all the necessary icons, the sample file below;

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faBuilding } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

library.add(faUserSecret,faTwitter,faBuilding)

Vue.component('fai', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

integrate the icons through nuxt.config.js, sample below;

```
plugins: [
  { src: '@/plugins/fontawesome.js', mode: 'client' }
]
```

Using the icons? see the sample below;

```
<div>
 <fai :icon="['fab', 'twitter']" />
</div>
```

**Few things to Note;**

1. <fai... /> is the component name, can name anything, needs to decide the name during component creation - Vue.component('**fai**', FontAwesomeIcon)
2. you import as faTwitter but you use as twitter, ommit fa and twitter starts small letter. If faUserSecret, then ommit fa and use user-secret.

Find vue-fontawesome full reference below;
https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:
in `nuxt.config.js` add this:

```
    script:[
      {src: "https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxxxx.js", crossorigin: "anonymous"},
    ],
```

Where `xxxxxxx` is the ID of your kit (created on FA website)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is placed within the `head` section of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faSms } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faFacebook, faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  console.log('[Plugin]', 'Font Awesome')
  library.add(faTwitter)
  library.add(faFacebook)
  library.add(faSms)
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
})
```